# OS X run command when Notification Center issues notification

Tags: macos, notifications, osx-mavericks, notificationcenter

I want to run a command (in this case, a command line program that [flickers the caps lock LED](http://googlemac.blogspot.de/2008/04/manipulating-keyboard-leds-through.html)) when I have an unread notification in Notification Center.

Is this possible?

Comment: It sounds feasible, if you can get a listener attached to the right notification. However, if you're using caps lock, it's going to be very annoying to users that are typing when they receive that notification!

Comment: Well the caps lock functionality has been completely disabled for a very long time. I just want to make use of the nice little LED that is sitting idle as a result. Already have a command line C program that I can call to toggle it, so I'm trying to come up with something to call it for.